# How to change PaymentURL in authorize.net?

Tags: ruby, authorize.net, activemerchant

I was integrated authorize.net with `ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetGateway` and It's working successfully. What I want, I want to change my URL - https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll  to  https://x1.cardknox.com/authorize. I don't know how to change URL in activeMerchant for authorize.net gateway.

So please help, if you have any idea how change url for authorize.net?

Thanks in Advance.